# UIlabel multiline in UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have problem with UILabel in UITableView. I want to bring film's plot in UILabel, but when application started, I have just one line of non-full plot, but when I scroll down and up, I get full film's plot with 2-3 lines. What problem can be?
[image: When application start]

[image: When scrolled down and back to film]

In UILabel preferences I choose 0 lines (It makes label is multiline).
In ViewController, in "viewDidLoad" I wrote two line of code, to make cell resizable:

```
self.searchTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
self.searchTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: Did you try `layoutIfNeeded` after get the text?

Comment: @anhtu No. How to use it?

Comment: @anhtu oh thank you, It really helps me!

Comment: e.g. :`view` (superview) of UILabel. Call `[view layoutIfNeeded]` after get text (after search)...

Comment: use the below delegate method to set the height. height can be calculated based on number of lines you calculated for a specific text in label.
- tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: Did you solve it? How? I will write an answer if it is solved.

Comment: @anhtu I'm used layoutIfNeeded. Ok, write answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `[view layoutIfNeeded]` after set the text of UILabel. It will layout subviews again.

Answer (score 4):

With UILabel over multiple lines, you have to give it a hand to know when to wrap text during layout.

To do this you need to set the `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` property. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/preferredMaxLayoutWidth

So in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method add something like:

```
cell.yourUILabelIBOutlet.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = tableView.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  Thank you!

Comment: For me this worked as well, the layoutIfNeeded didn't!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using autolayout in UITableViewCell. it's working for me.

- Add UILabel in your tableview
- Set UILabel Leading,Trailling,top and bottom constraints.(Note : don't set height for that label)
- Then set UILabel NO.Of line 0 and set Line Break mode.

Set your tableview cell height

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

      tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 150
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the below code and try it. It works##

> -(void)viewDidLoad {
>       [super viewDidLoad];
>   //at last line of viewDidLoad
>       [self performSelector:@selector(reloadtable) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
>   }
>
> -(void)reloadtable 
>   {
>       [self.tableView reloadData];
>   
>   }